# Report manager for SSRS 2005 not opening

Tags: sql-server-2005, reporting-services, iis-6

I have an issue while opening Report Manager for SSRS reports built in BIDS 2005. 
Virtual directories named ReportServer and Reports get created on IIS for reportserver and report manager respectively. But when ReportServer directory is browsed in IIS, an error occurs saying:

```
'An internal error occurred on the report server. See the error log for more details. (rsInternalError) Get Online Help
Object reference not set to an instance of an object'
```

Tried reading the event log but could not make out anything from it.

I Restarted IIS and then Reporting services, Checked if the user has admin rights and it does have. But still the problem persists.

Please let me know what could be the possible checks....

Note : I am using Windows Server 2003, IIS 6.0 and SQL Server 2005

Answer (score 0):

Try the SSRS log files for more clues, they will be located around here (varies depending on your versions and configurations):

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS10_50.SQLEXPRESS\Reporting Services\LogFiles
```

There are some very detailed messages.  Open them in a text editor.